# Understanding the second part of the proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $F$ be a free group on n generators, say $x_1, ..., x_n$  . For a word $w\in F$ , define $l_i(w)$ to be the sum of all the exponents of $x_i$ occuring in $w$. For a subset $I$ of $\lbrace 1 ,2 ,...,n \rbrace$ , and a positive integer  l , define $$\Gamma_l(I)=\lbrace  w\in F:l_i(w)\equiv0 \ (mod \ l) \ \forall i\in I\rbrace  .$$Show that $\Gamma_l(I)$ is a normal subgroup of F of index $l^{|I|}$ .

proof: Normality is evident since $\Gamma_l(I)$ is the kernel of the surjective homomorphism $F \rightarrow (Z/lZ)^{|I|}$ sending $w$ to $(l_i(w))_{i \in I}$ . It is easily seen that $$ \lbrace \prod_{i \in I}x_i^{e_i}:0\leq e_i<l \rbrace $$is a set of (left) coset representatives of $\Gamma_l(I)$ in $F$ , from which the result is
evident.

My problem is to understand why it is important to mention the second part  about the representatives and how to find them .

Comment: From a surjective homomorphism $\phi$ you have the kernel and its index and the cosets $\phi^{-1}(e)$ telling the quotient group $F/ker(\phi) = \bigcup_{e \in (Z/lZ)^{|I|}} \phi^{-1}(e)$